# My mailserver cant accept emails error 454 4.7.1 email@domain.tld: Relay access denied

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot

sending emails is okay, I can send event to gmail. But when I send email from gmail, I've got error  `454 4.7.1 email@domain.tld: Relay access denied`

I am using `postfix` with `dovecot`.

I have sadly no idea where is the problem.. Here is my `postfix main.cf`.

```
myhostname = server-hostname.tld
mydestination = server-hostname.tld, localhost, localhost.localdomain
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_uids.cf
virtual_gid_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_gids.cf
sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_outgoing_bcc.cf
inet_protocols = all
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_restriction_classes = greylisting
greylisting = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender_login_maps.cf
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $sender_bcc_maps $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $smtpd_sender_login_maps
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/helo_access, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/blacklist_helo
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_originating.re , permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf, check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_foreign.re
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_transport = dovecot
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
owner_request_special = no
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had badly configured MX records. Had to put there hostname of domain and server to MX records.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add `domain.tld` (or whatever your real domain is) to Postfix's `mydestination` configuration setting, otherwise Postfix won't recognize the mail should be delivered locally. See Postfix's [Basic Configuration Readme](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html).

Comment: Sadly did not worked :(

Comment: And restart the service  +1